# How to show friends list from Facebook like Tinder dose on the Profile section?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-sdk-3.0

I would like to know how to show friends from Facebook like on the app "Tinder" (on the profile section of Tinder), which is basically one horizontal cell that shows all your Facebook friends.

I know how to fetch user's friends from Facebook using the `FacebookSDK` and i know how to make the profile picture rounded, which it's only this line of code- `self.ProfilePictureView.layar.cornerRadius = ....`

I just don't know how to implement that cell to present the friends list.

Please, if anyone can help...
Thanks anyway!

Comment: check [facebook tutorial link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps/)  FriendPickerSample

Comment: In order to reply you question i have to see on net that how the tinder display user (the design of cell) and all have to do same thing, It will be good if you just post image of it overt here.

Comment: Hey @Jageen thanks for your answer.
about the picture, if you go to [this link](http://btekt.com/reviews/116/tinder-review) and scroll it to the middle, you'll see a man (Basil, 29) with his 684 friends.
i'm sorry that i didn't post an image, cause I'm new here...

Comment: @pawan thanks! but i know how to do it that way...
i don't know how to call what i'm looking for, but it's kind of a horizontal table view...

Comment: can you drop a  sketch image , how you want it in cell?

Comment: i think you need to customize FBFriendPickerViewController [link](http://blog.grio.com/2012/10/customizing-the-facebook-ios-sdk-fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-adding-a-search-bar.html)

Answer (score 1):

for this condition, you need to implement your own facebook picker.
here is  snippet from one of my project. 
it return the list of your friend. you can show it in  your table view  & customize the tableview cell with round corner.

check this

```
- (void)getFriends:(void(^)(NSArray *friends, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
friendsRequest.session = [FBSession activeSession];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
        return;
    }

    NSArray* friends = result[@"data"];
    completionBlock(friends, nil);
}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! i'll try to build it with a custom table view.
i'll publish it here when i figure it out.